# Stringing together multiple Photoshop CS4 Actions

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I'm having a mess about with Photoshop CS4 actions to cut up an image and save each image as it's own file. Easy enough, but I have about 30 different images to make each time. So, I had a play about with actions, and thinking I understood it, recorded what I wanted and hit play.

However I soon realised I need to run each cut as a seperate action.

Which is where my problem comes in.

How do I do this and run all these actions in one go? I had a look at scripts, but this didn't seem to be much help.

Any ideas?!
Cheers

Comment: I have managed to do this but not ideally. You can 'shift click' and highlight all the actions you want then run them... it works but still not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to run actions (as you would use a tool) while you are recording.

When recording an action, if you select another action in the *actions panel* you can run it and it gets embedded (referenced) in the action you're currently recording.

[image]

Comment: Nice one, thats what I wanted... I also ended up finding out which function ran actions using javascript...
doAction("ActionName","ActionSet")
I'm not a fan of javasctript thats for sure!